# Coordinates to wkt OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers

**Hello friends, I need to convert the coordinates I received in my project with openlayers to wkt, I would appreciate it if you could help me.**

**Coordinate information I received:**

> `(2) [32.834075024001905, 39.978537003695095]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WKT.html

your solution could look like this

```
var format = new ol.format.WKT(),
wkt = format.writeGeometry(yourFeature.getGeometry());
```